# Why does DatePlus[] return different result for String date vs DateObject date?

Tags: bugs, date-and-time

### Bug introduced in v12.1.1 or earlier and fixed in v13.0.0

---

I am on Mathematica 12.1.1, running the following code and getting different results. Is it bug in DatePlus?

Setup

```
date1 = DateObject[{2020, 1, 30}]
activitytimeperiodcoveredbyoneperiodicpayment = "Month"
rng = Range[5]
```

Execution of DatePlus[]:

```
DatePlus[DateString[date1, "ISODate"], {#, 
    activitytimeperiodcoveredbyoneperiodicpayment}] & /@ rng
DatePlus[date1, {#, 
    activitytimeperiodcoveredbyoneperiodicpayment}] & /@ rng
```

Result:

````
{"Sat 29 Feb 2020 00:00:00", "Mon 30 Mar 2020 00:00:00", "Thu 30 Apr \
2020 00:00:00", "Sat 30 May 2020 00:00:00", "Tue 30 Jun 2020 \
00:00:00"}

{DateObject[{2020, 3, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -4.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 3, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian", -4.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 4, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian", -4.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 5, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian", -4.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 6, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian", -4.]}
```
````

Comment: Mathematica behaves differently with `DateObject` than `DateList` or `DateString` input, in your case, with `DateObject` it increases month without controlling the day overflow (we don't have 2020-2-30) so it goes to the next month, but with other types, it snaps to the last possible day without overflowing.

Comment: Exactly. Allowing some types to overflow and others not is inconsistent result from `DatePlus` and/or a bug in `DateObject`.

Answer (score 0):

I find that it is more convenient to use `EndOfMonth` in such cases.
I would define a safe date, for instance the beginning of the month, do the monthly shifts and then ask for the end of month.

```
date2 = DatePlus[date1, {-1, "BeginningOfMonth"}]

DatePlus[DateString[date2, "ISODate"], 
  {{#, activitytimeperiodcoveredbyoneperiodicpayment}, {1, "EndOfMonth"}}] & /@ rng
DatePlus[date2, 
  {{#, activitytimeperiodcoveredbyoneperiodicpayment}, {1, "EndOfMonth"}}] & /@ rng

(* 
{"Sat 29 Feb 2020 00:00:00", "Tue 31 Mar 2020 00:00:00", "Thu 30 Apr \
2020 00:00:00", "Sun 31 May 2020 00:00:00", "Tue 30 Jun 2020 00:00:00"}

{DateObject[{2020, 2, 29}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 3, 31}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 4, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 5, 31}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 6, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.]}
*)
```

Comment: `EndOfMonth` is useful but in this case the day of each month is the 30th. For some months, like April, 30th is `EndOfMonth`. For other, like January, 30th is not. And then there is February, where `EndOfMonth` could be 28th or 29th.

Comment: I think that the examples above return the correct end of month in all instances you mentioned - am I missing your point ?

Comment: 30 Jan 2020 plus one month is 29 Feb 2020. 30 Jan 2020 plus two months is 30 Mar 2020. 30 Jan 2020 plus three months is 30 Apr 2020.